# EDMX taking reference of deleted table of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

Initially I had two tables in SQL Server - `ProjectRequest` and `bkpProjectRequest`. I never added the second one into my `edmx` file.

But when I try to save the record it is taking reference of `bkpProjectRequest` table. I deleted it from database. Now it is throwing error

> Invalid object name 'bkpProjectRequest'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Delete both tables from edmx.

Step 2: Delete bkpProjectRequests (you've already done this).

Step 3: From edmx right click and choose "Update model from database" and select "ProjectRequest"

It should be now without reference to bkpProjectRequests.

Comment: I have deleted all the tables from edmx and re-added all the tables. Still facing issue. Still I am not able to understand there is no reference between these two tables. bkp is just a back up of table. I don't know why entity framework considering this table to add records

Comment: There is no reference between 2 tables now, but I guess there was a reference between tables before, right? So, even when EF is updated and have no reference on bkp table, in your code you have an reference to that table. Run your code in debug mode and see in which line you have an error.

Comment: Yes, there was a reference. It was my mistake. Your solution worked.